# Finding the divergence of this force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differentiation, vector-fields

I've got to find the divergence of this force,
$$
\mathbf F=\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^n\left(x\hat e_x+y\hat e_y+z\hat e_z\right)
$$
I would know how to do it if the $n$ superscript wasn't there. Any ideas on this one?

Comment: Hint: For $y=f(x)^n$, $dy/dx=nf(x)^{n-1}(df/dx)$. You'll have to apply this a few times.

Comment: One of my faves: "Div, grad, curl, and all that," by Schey.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the definition http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence
and the fact that $ x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=r^{2}$
$\nabla\cdot F = r^{2n}+2nx^2r^{2(n-1)}+r^{2n}+2ny^2r^{2(n-1)}+r^{2n}+2nz^2r^{2(n-1)} = 3r^{2n}+2nr^{2n}$

Comment: We generally try to avoid giving a *complete* answer to homework problems here, because that doesn't help much toward the questioners learning the material that they're studying.  Instead, it's better to just give enough of a hint that the questioners are able to solve their homework problems themselves.  See http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange